# Span Right in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have my buttons on right side of the navbar, but there are no changes. **[See Demo](http://jainvidhya.co.in/testing.php)**.

Helpful Codes:

```
.money_right {
  float: right
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-blue fixed-top">
  <span style="color: white;"><b>GUEST</b></span>&nbsp;
     <span class="money_right">
        <button class="money_bronze"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_silver"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_gold"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="gems"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
    </span>
</nav>
```

I tried to have a working demo at **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sk5wg0v/9/)** but some `CSS` wor not implemented there, so this is my **[Working Demo](http://jainvidhya.co.in/testing.php)**.

Comment: you are using bootstrap 4 no need float, you simply need to read the doc more carefully to understand the class you are using . Remove the `navbar-expand-lg` and the float and it will work

Comment: What's wrong with the demo?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thankyou so much it helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on Bootstrap 4 - I mention this only because the code in your question is formatted for Bootstrap 4, but the Fiddle you're linking relies on Bootstrap 3.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold">GUEST</div>
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <button class="money_bronze font-weight-bold">0</button>
    <button class="money_silver font-weight-bold">0</button>
    <button class="money_gold font-weight-bold">0</button>
    <button class="gems font-weight-bold">0</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

While I've edited your overall code to rely more on Bootstrap 4s built in utility classes, the real key here is `ml-auto`.  This pushes the content to the right in Bootstrap 4 in a flexbox display method - no troublesome `float`!

Since `<button>` defaults to `inline-block` which creates white space automatically I've also removed your `&nbsp;` as they are superfluous.  For more space or better precision I highly recommend using the `mx-*` utility class.

Answer (score 1):

try to add attribute  dir="rtl"

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<nav dir="rtl" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-blue fixed-top">
  <span style="color: white;"><b>GUEST</b></span>&nbsp;
     <span class="money_right">
        <button class="money_bronze"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_silver"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_gold"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="gems"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
    </span>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you serious ? ... first you didn't include all his code as he's using bootstrap, then check well the white text that is not visible here ... and you got upvoted ...

Comment: yes very suspicious upvotes for a wrong answer ... let's flag a moderator ;)

Comment: i don t have all his code but he's specified just  on right side

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.money_right {
  float: right
}`

from your code and also remove `"navbar-expand-lg"` class from your nav tag.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-blue fixed-top">
  <span style="color: white;"><b>GUEST</b></span>&nbsp;
     <span class="money_right">
        <button class="money_bronze"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_silver"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="money_gold"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="gems"><b>0</b></button>&nbsp;
    </span>
</nav>
```

and you are done.